# Perl - .htaccess How do I redirect incoming query by popping off part of string

Tags: .htaccess

I need to add this function to my .htaccess file.

I have this query coming in from other domains.

```
http://Domain.com/some-folder/blue-widget/large/bluewidget-number-yada-60467.htm
```

I need that to go to:

```
http://Domain.com/60467
```

I found a way to match 5 or 6 digits .htm at the end of the query but, how do I implement this as a "redirect"?

```
<FilesMatch "\d{5,6}\.htm?$">
```

in something like:

```
RewriteRule \d{5,6}\.htm?$ http://Domain.com/60467
```

Do I need a rewrite Condition first?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\d{5,6}\.htm?$)
```

Here is the hard part.
Is it also possible the have it ignore that rule if the query is generated from the domain the .htaccess is located on (Domain.com)? Not necessary but, I would like to be able to do that too.

I really cannot figure this out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any query strings in this URL:

```
http://Domain.com/some-folder/blue-widget/large/bluewidget-number-yada-60467.htm
```

there isn't any `?` in the URL. To redirect something like that, you don't need a condition, something like this should be good enough:

```
RedirectMatch -([0-9]+)\.htm$ /$1
```

or if you need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRUle -([0-9]+)\.htm$ /$1 [L,R]
```